Como habilitar getUserMedia en Chrome para iOS no abre cámara
Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web que te permite tomar fotos, en chrome de android funciona bien, en pc también, pero en chrome para iphone no funciona, intenté habilitar insecure origins treated as secure en chrome de ios pero no me aparece la opción. Les dejo mi código:


var idItem = 0;
var sucEvaluada = 0;
var fechaEv = '';
var itm = '';
var idct = 0;

function asgIdItem(idItems, idSucV, fechaV, item, idcat) {
    idItem = idItems;
    sucEvaluada = idSucV;
    fechaEv = fechaV;
    itm = item;
    idct = idcat;

    // console.log('hola');
    // console.log(idItem, sucEvaluada, fechaEv);
}

var tieneSoporteUserMedia = () =>
    !!(navigator.getUserMedia || (navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia)
var _getUserMedia = (...arguments) =>
    (navigator.getUserMedia || (navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia).apply(navigator, arguments);

// Declaramos elementos del DOM
var $video = document.querySelector("#video"),
    $canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas"),
    $estado = document.querySelector("#estado"),
    $botonFoto = document.querySelector("#botonFoto"),
    $listaDeDispositivos = document.querySelector("#listaDeDispositivos");

var limpiarSelect = () => {
    for (let x = $listaDeDispositivos.options.length - 1; x >= 0; x--)
        $listaDeDispositivos.remove(x);
};
var obtenerDispositivos = () => navigator
    .mediaDevices
    .enumerateDevices();

// La función que es llamada después de que ya se dieron los permisos
// Lo que hace es llenar el select con los dispositivos obtenidos
var llenarSelectConDispositivosDisponibles = () => {

    limpiarSelect();
    obtenerDispositivos()
        .then(dispositivos => {
            const dispositivosDeVideo = [];
            dispositivos.forEach(dispositivo => {
                const tipo = dispositivo.kind;
                if (tipo === "videoinput") {
                    dispositivosDeVideo.push(dispositivo);
                }
            });

            // Vemos si encontramos algún dispositivo, y en caso de que si, entonces llamamos a la función
            if (dispositivosDeVideo.length > 0) {
                // Llenar el select
                dispositivosDeVideo.forEach(dispositivo => {
                    const option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.value = dispositivo.deviceId;
                    option.text = dispositivo.label;
                    $listaDeDispositivos.appendChild(option);
                });
            }
        });
}

(function () {
    // Comenzamos viendo si tiene soporte, si no, nos detenemos
    if (!tieneSoporteUserMedia()) {
        alert("Lo siento. Tu navegador no soporta esta característica");
        $estado.innerHTML = "Parece que tu navegador no soporta esta característica. Intenta actualizarlo.";
        return;
    }
    //Aquí guardaremos el stream globalmente
    let stream;


    // Comenzamos pidiendo los dispositivos
    obtenerDispositivos()
        .then(dispositivos => {
            // Vamos a filtrarlos y guardar aquí los de vídeo
            const dispositivosDeVideo = [];

            // Recorrer y filtrar
            dispositivos.forEach(function (dispositivo) {
                const tipo = dispositivo.kind;
                if (tipo === "videoinput") {
                    dispositivosDeVideo.push(dispositivo);
                }
            });

            // Vemos si encontramos algún dispositivo, y en caso de que si, entonces llamamos a la función
            // y le pasamos el id de dispositivo
            if (dispositivosDeVideo.length > 0) {
                // Mostrar stream con el ID del primer dispositivo, luego el usuario puede cambiar
                mostrarStream(dispositivosDeVideo[0].deviceId);
            }
        });



    const mostrarStream = idDeDispositivo => {
        _getUserMedia({
            video: {
                // Justo aquí indicamos cuál dispositivo usar
                deviceId: idDeDispositivo,
            }
        },
            (streamObtenido) => {
                // Aquí ya tenemos permisos, ahora sí llenamos el select,
                // pues si no, no nos daría el nombre de los dispositivos
                llenarSelectConDispositivosDisponibles();

                // Escuchar cuando seleccionen otra opción y entonces llamar a esta función
                $listaDeDispositivos.onchange = () => {
                    // Detener el stream
                    if (stream) {
                        stream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {
                            track.stop();
                        });
                    }
                    // Mostrar el nuevo stream con el dispositivo seleccionado
                    mostrarStream($listaDeDispositivos.value);
                }

                // Simple asignación
                stream = streamObtenido;

                // Mandamos el stream de la cámara al elemento de vídeo
                $video.srcObject = stream;
                $video.play();

                //Escuchar el click del botón para tomar la foto
                //Escuchar el click del botón para tomar la foto
                $botonFoto.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    //Pausar reproducción



                    $video.pause();

                    //Obtener contexto del canvas y dibujar sobre él
                    let contexto = $canvas.getContext("2d");
                    $canvas.width = $video.videoWidth;
                    $canvas.height = $video.videoHeight;
                    contexto.drawImage($video, 0, 0, $canvas.width, $canvas.height);

                    let foto = $canvas.toDataURL(); //Esta es la foto, en base 64
                    $estado.innerHTML = "Enviando foto. Por favor, espera...";
                    fetch("../guardar_foto.php", {
                        method: "POST",
                        body: encodeURIComponent(foto),
                        headers: {
                            "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        }
                    })
                        .then(resultado => {
                            // A los datos los decodificamos como texto plano
                            return resultado.text()
                        })
                        .then(nombreDeLaFoto => {
                            // nombreDeLaFoto trae el nombre de la imagen que le dio PHP
                            console.log("La foto fue enviada correctamente");
                            console.log(nombreDeLaFoto);

                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: 'addPhoto.php',
                                data: { 'nombreFoto': nombreDeLaFoto, 'idItem': idItem, 'sucEvaluada': sucEvaluada, 'fechaEv': fechaEv, 'item': itm, 'idCat': idct },

                                success: function (data) {
                                    $('#probando').html(data);
                                }
                            });

                            $estado.innerHTML = `Foto guardada con éxito. Puedes verla <a target='_blank' href='./${nombreDeLaFoto}'> aquí</a>`;
                        })

                    //Reanudar reproducción
                    $video.play();
                });
            }, (error) => {
                console.log("Permiso denegado o error: ", error);
                $estado.innerHTML = "No se puede acceder a la cámara, o no diste permiso.";
            });
    }
})();


function modalImg(imagen) {

    document.getElementById('ImagenGde').src = document.getElementById(imagen).src;

    $('#modalImg').modal('show');

}

$(function () {
    $('input[name="submitFoto"]').on('click', function () {
        var file_data = $('.file').prop('files')[0];
        if (file_data != undefined) {
            var form_data = new FormData();
            form_data.append('file', file_data);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'subirArchivoImg.php',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response == 'success') {

                        // console.log(file_data.name);
                        nombreDeLaFoto = 'evaluaciones/fotos/' + file_data.name;

                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'addPhoto.php',
                            data: { 'nombreFoto': nombreDeLaFoto, 'idItem': idItem, 'sucEvaluada': sucEvaluada, 'fechaEv': fechaEv, 'item': itm, 'idCat': idct },

                            success: function (data) {
                                // $('#probando').html(data);
                            }
                        });

                        alert('File uploaded successfully.');
                    } else {
                        alert('Something went wrong. Please try again.');
                    }

                    $('.file').val('');
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
                        <div>
                            <select name="listaDeDispositivos" id="listaDeDispositivos"></select>
                            <button id="botonFoto" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Tomar foto</button>
                            <p id="estado"></p>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <!-- <video muted="muted" id="video"></video> -->
                        <video id="video" muted autoplay playsinline></video>



Como digo, funciona bien en Android y Pc, si me abre la cámara, pero en  iOs no he encontrado la manera en que funcione, tampoco encuentro la opcion para habilitar archivos desconocidos.
Otra opción que he pensado es poniendo para que suban archivos y que de ahí tome la cámara, no sé si me puedan orientar sobre el tema

"no funciona" es ambiguo. Explicate mejor: no abre la cámara, no toma la foto, no envía la foto, la foto no llega al otro lado, la aplicación no parte ...

no abre la camara para tomar la foto

Qué pasa si usas Safari? algún prompt que te pide dar permisos para usar la cámara?
